# Collapsible components , target and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-collapse.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) for collapsible components.

What I am trying to do is to matche the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Here is an example of html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#child">Collapse</button>

<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <textarea id="child">
        asdads
        asdasdas
    </textarea>
</div>​
```

As you can see I would like to collapse `.parent` not just the `#child`.
How should I do it?
Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Re8Av/10/

P.S.:

data-target=".parent" does not work because I have a lot of these components.